# Using asio coroutine with user-defined data structure instead of a (asio) socket?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, coroutine

Boost asio's coroutine examples show how a yield context can be passed as completion handler to a socket:

```
socket.async_read_some(buffer, yield);
```

Can a user-defined data structure be implemented to provide the same functionality as the socket?

My aim is to implement a (single-threaded) packet processing where coroutines act like fibers:

```
// coroutine which demultiplexes into tcp and udp 
void packet_processor(boost::asio::yield_context yield)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        auto packet = input_queue.pop(yield); 
        if (packet.is_tcp())
        {
            tcp_queue.push(packet);
        }
        else if (packet.is_udp())
        {
            udp_queue.push(packet);
        }
    }
}

// coroutine which handles UDP datagrams
void udp_processor(boost::asio::yield_context yield)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        auto udp_segment = udp_queue.pop(yield);
        process(udp_segment);
    }
}


// coroutine which handles tcp segments
void tcp_processor(boost::asio::yield_context yield)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        auto tcp_segment = tcp_queue.pop(yield);
        process(tcp_segment);
    }
}
```

Could above code be made to work?

Comment: Is it okay for the user-defined structure to be `io_service` aware and/or does the user-defined structure provide an event-based API?  Also, I think the Boost-1.59 build on Coliru may be a release-candidate.  In particular, the Boost.Coroutine looks out of date ([demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49873fe35e04a615)).

Comment: Yes, the structure could know about the `io_service`. And it can provide an event-based api (most likely also powered by the ios).

Comment: @TannerSansbury I'm aware of some weird linker issues with recent boost on coliru. I'll try to fix it soon.

Comment: I took a quick pass at this over the weekend: [demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1dc4024e72e06024). Once I have some time, I will try to follow up to this question with a detailed answer.